# Using Having clause with multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can I use `having` with multiple clauses ?

Like that one but this doesn't work

```
HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) > 0, COUNT(t3.ID) > 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `AND` or `OR` operator between the conditions.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
HAVING COUNT(colA) > 4 AND MAX(colB) = 3
```

you could also apply grouping.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
HAVING (COUNT(colA) > 4 AND MAX(colB) = 3) OR 
       SUM(colC) > 100
```

Answer (score 3):

No comma, use ANDS

```
HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) > 0 and COUNT(t3.ID) > 0
```

Having must result in a boolean expression to check whether the grouped result is filtered or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Having count(t2.id) > 0 and count(t3.id) > 0
```